# IE8 hover over iframe and js in list (no href!)

Tags: css, iframe, internet-explorer-8, hover, html-lists

I am trying to create a customized social media share list with href links with icons to some social media (twitter etc.)
The `<ul>` list also includes two "external" elements that are not simple href links:

- Facebook "Like" button as iFrame, and
- Google +1 button as js

See simplified example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milanouser/V35BC/)

In order to de-clutter my site I decided to show only one row of icons (links), with the other ones only visible when *hovering* over the wrapping div (similar to sexybookmarks plugin for wordpress, just without the nasty user tracking).

This works fine in all browsers except IE8 (shockingly... I discard IE7 and older):
both FB "Like" and "g+1" buttons are visible when hovering over the href links, but disappear immediately when trying to hover over or click these buttons.

Try resizing the window to have only three "icons" visible: hovering over the other two href "icons" works just fine, but hovering over the "like" and "1+" won't work

This makes me believe that the problem is that IE8 does not recognize the iframe and js within list elements as valid elements that can be hovered. How could that be solved?

I am aware that IE8 has an issue with hovering in general, but I could not find any solution to this particular problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should remove your Google Analytics code from the fiddle ;) and - I don't really know what is your problem. Hovering on div.socialbar just makes the G+ and FB buttons visible on FF/IE8/IE9.

Comment: Hi firian, thanks for your comment. The problem is that hovering does yes show the two buttons, but you cannot click on them! They disappear in IE8.
As for Google analytics: ??? does that come with the G+ button? You know a way to get rid of that crap?